# Simple Binary Image Classification (Person / No Person) in `C`

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, machine-learning, classification, software-implementation

i have to do a project for university which is basically to program a tool to classify small greyscale images like those below into person or non-person, in C.

[image]
[image] [image] [image]

The project is scheduled for around 2 months of work.
However, the approaches i found on the internet all use high-level tools like Matlab or Python with OpenCV. Using those, i will get the job way too quickly and easily.

So i need an idea on how to do a lower level implementation in C, that will take me like 1-2 months.

Maybe someone can help me out with a useful approach.

Comment: MATLAB is rich in image processing functions that indeed do the work quickly and easily. Why don't you try the approaches you found but build everything from scratch in C? You can also find some standard image processing libraries in C to help you start.

Comment: What's the point of this project? If you're trying to learn C, go with @GKH's advice. Otherwise, this project will be a lot of pain for little gain (IMHO).

Comment: Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let's split the problem into 2:

1. Extracting Features
   You will find `C` based low level image processing framework (Intel IPP, [Leptonica Library](https://github.com/danbloomberg/leptonica), [LibVIPS](https://github.com/libvips/libvips)). You can also use the book [Dwayne Phillips - Image Processing in C](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/PHILLIPS/cips2ed.pdf). This step is mainly about extracting meaningful features from the image.
2. Classifier
   The easiest classifier to implement in `C` would be [Logistic Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). You have the gradient in a closed form which will make life easy for you.

You could also use [SOD](https://github.com/symisc/sod) as *all in one* solution in `C`.